# How to reuse overloaded function types and assign it to another function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function (wrapper over a React `useEffect` hook) to handle API calls. It is declared as follows:

```
export type StreamHook<Data, Callback> = [{ loading: boolean, data: Data | null, error: any }, Callback];

export function useAsyncAction<Data>(callback: () => Promise<Data>): StreamHook<Data, () => void>;
export function useAsyncAction<A1, Data>(callback: (a1: A1) => Promise<Data>): StreamHook<Data, (a1: A1) => void>;
export function useAsyncAction<A1, A2, Data>(callback: (a1: A1, a2: A2) => Promise<Data>): StreamHook<Data, (a1: A1, a2: A2) => void>;
export function useAsyncAction<A1, A2, A3, Data>(callback: (a1: A1, a2: A2, a3: A3) => Promise<Data>): StreamHook<Data, (a1: A1, a2: A2, a3: A3) => void>;
export function useAsyncAction<A1, A2, A3, A4, Data>(callback: (a1: A1, a2: A2, a3: A3, a4: A4) => Promise<Data>): StreamHook<Data, (a1: A1, a2: A2, a3: A3, a4: A4) => void>;
export function useAsyncAction<Data>(callback: (...args: any[]) => Promise<Data>): StreamHook<Data, any> {
  // Implementation details
}
```

I am wrapping this `function` with some additional behavior. Writing the types again is cumbersome and error-prone. So, is there a way to reuse this type signature and apply it to some other signature. I tried the following but it doesn't seems to work with overloaded signatures.

```
export type AsyncAction = typeof useAsyncAction;

// Expected to have automatically inferred type for callback.
export const useAsyncActionWrapper: AsyncAction = (callback) => {
  const action = useAsyncAction(callback);

  return action;
};
```

It cannot properly infers the type signature for `callback` argument. The error is:

`Parameter 'callback' implicitly has an 'any' type`.

Also, if I provide the type info for the callback, it doesn't match with any overloaded definition. Any way to address this?